# DES encrypted value mismatching android and ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, encryption

**IOS code is**

```
#import "DESCodec.h"
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCryptor.h>


@implementation DESCodec
{
 NSString *key;
}

-(id) init{
self=[super init];
if(self){
    key=@"12345678";
}
return self;
}

-(NSString *) decode:(NSString *)encoded{
    NSData *inputData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:encoded options:0];
    NSData *keyData = [key dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    size_t outLength;

    NSMutableData *outputData = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:(inputData.length  + 

 kCCBlockSizeDES)];

CCCryptorStatus
result = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt, // operation
                 kCCAlgorithmDES, // Algorithm
                 kCCOptionPKCS7Padding , // options
                 keyData.bytes, // key
                 keyData.length, // keylength
                 nil,// iv
                 inputData.bytes, // dataIn
                 inputData.length, // dataInLength,
                 outputData.mutableBytes, // dataOut
                 outputData.length, // dataOutAvailable
                 &outLength); // dataOutMoved

if (result != kCCSuccess) {
    return nil;
}
[outputData setLength:outLength];
return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:outputData `encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`
}


-(NSString *) encode:(NSString *)decoded{

NSData *inputData = [decoded dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData *keyData = [key dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
size_t outLength;

NSMutableData *outputData = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:(inputData.length  +  kCCBlockSizeDES)];

CCCryptorStatus result = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt, // operation
                                 kCCAlgorithmDES, // Algorithm
                                 kCCOptionPKCS7Padding, // options
                                 keyData.bytes, // key
                                 keyData.length, // keylength
                                 nil,// iv
                                 inputData.bytes, // dataIn
                                 inputData.length, // dataInLength,
                                 outputData.mutableBytes, // dataOut
                                 outputData.length, // dataOutAvailable
                                 &outLength); // dataOutMoved

if (result != kCCSuccess) {
    return nil;
}
[outputData setLength:outLength];
NSString *r = [outputData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];


    return r;
}

@end

DESCodec *codec=[[DESCodec alloc] init];
NSString *encoded=[codec encode:@"12345678"];
NSString decoded=[codec decode:encoded];
NSLog(@" %@ %@",encoded,decoded);
```

value is ltACiHjVjImOJQ1fTHZkSw== and 12345678

but in java encypted text is "ltACiHjVjIn+uVm31GQvyw=="

I not good in Objective C and I can't able to trigger out the problem.

can anybody please help me. Thanks and regards

**Java code is**

```
public class DESCodec {

    /**
     * Secret key that shall be used for encryption and decryption.
     */
    private String strSecretKey = "12345678";

    private static final String UNICODE_FORMAT = "UTF-8";

    private static final String DES_ENCRYPTION_SCHEME = "DES";

    private static final String TAG = "DESCodec";

    private Cipher cipher;

    private SecretKey key;


    public DESCodec() {
        try {
            this.strSecretKey = strSecretKey;
            String myEncryptionScheme = DES_ENCRYPTION_SCHEME;
            byte[] keyAsBytes = strSecretKey.getBytes(UNICODE_FORMAT);
            DESKeySpec myKeySpec = new DESKeySpec(keyAsBytes);
            SecretKeyFactory mySecretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(myEncryptionScheme);
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance(myEncryptionScheme);
            key = mySecretKeyFactory.generateSecret(myKeySpec);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    public String desEncrypt(String message) {
        String encryptedString = null;
        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
            byte[] plainText = message.getBytes(UNICODE_FORMAT);
            byte[] encryptedText = cipher.doFinal(plainText);

            encryptedString = Base64.encodeToString(encryptedText, Base64.DEFAULT);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return encryptedString;
    }

    public String desDecrypt(String message) {
        String decryptedText = null;
        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
            byte[] encryptedText = Base64.decode(message, Base64.DEFAULT);
            byte[] plainText = cipher.doFinal(encryptedText);
            decryptedText = bytes2String(plainText);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return decryptedText;
    }

    private String bytes2String(byte[] bytes) {
        try {
            return new String(bytes, UNICODE_FORMAT);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's obviously only a problem with the mode of operation, because the first block matches. In Java you're using ECB mode, because "DES" defaults to "DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding". I think that CCCryptor defaults to CBC.

---

Don't ever use ECB mode. It's not semantically secure. You need to use at least CBC mode with a random IV. The IV doesn't have to be secret, so you can prepend it to the ciphertext. Please look at RNCryptor that has additional security features like authentication of ciphertext. It also has a Java implementation.

Don't use DES anymore. It's not secure anymore. You should use AES. Triple DES is also not that bad.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...I am just added the java code. If you don't mind please look it. Thanks again

Comment: Sorry to disturb you again, I am beginner to objective c. Can you please correct my code. Thanks

Comment: I fixed my answer a little. You shouldn't use DES anymore. Change it to a more modern cipher.

Answer (score 0):

I hava the same problem when i develop an iOS app.And the android client is used by many people, so i couldn't change the algorithm to AES or others.As Artjom B. said in Java 'DES' defaults to 'DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding', in the source you can find that

```
Cipher c1 = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
```

but unfortunately in iOS you just find that

```
enum {
    kCCOptionPKCS7Padding = 0x0001,
    kCCOptionECBMode      = 0x0002
}
```

But finally i find a solution like this

```
CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt,
                              kCCAlgorithmDES,
                              kCCOptionPKCS7Padding | kCCOptionECBMode,
                              [key UTF8String],
                              kCCKeySizeDES,
                              nil,
                              [cipherData bytes],
                              [cipherData length],
                              buffer,
                              1024,
                              &numBytesDecrypted);
```

The importance is `kCCOptionPKCS7Padding | kCCOptionECBMode`, you can try this method.

Comment: Just wondering why you are using DES as it is very insecure, is security really that unimportant to you and your users?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I totally agree wtih you. And I just fix fix this problem with no other better solution because I can't modify the code on the server.In fact, I think RSA+AES is a good choice when app associates with the client.Thanks for your suggestion again.

Comment: So, would a bridge design engineer use inferior old rusty beams? Oh, I get it, he is a professional and would not do that, we are just code-monkeys.